# What's wrong with ng2-dragula based grid?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, gridview, ng2-dragula

I want to use ng2-dragula to build drag & drop grid based experience.
Seems like ng2-dragula is the way to go.

I imported it into a blank project and if I have a simple vertical list (below). It works fine.

[image]

Now if I want to make this a horizontal list - the dragging already has slight delays or is not precise:

[image]

Finally if I keep the screen small enough for it to become a grid - the experience is even worse;( it is not precise and its hard to do dragging-dropping.

[image]

**Question: 
- is it possible to use ng2-dragula for a grid use case? documentation has no examples or guidance re this. What do I miss to make this actually work?**

My blank app code below:

```js
import {
  Component,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  NavController
} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('thegrid') gridElement: ElementRef;

  dragTarget: any = null;
  grid: any;
  items: Array < any > ;
  placeholder = {
    index: 11,
    style: {
      background: "black"
    },
    class: {
      gridItem: true, dragged: false
    }
  }

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public renderer: Renderer2
  ) {

    this.items = [{
        index: 0
      },
      {
        index: 1
      },
      {
        index: 2
      },
      {
        index: 3
      },
      {
        index: 4
      },
      {
        index: 5
      },
      {
        index: 6
      },
      {
        index: 7
      },
      {
        index: 8
      },
      {
        index: 9
      },
      {
        index: 10
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

```css
page-home {
  .noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .gridItem {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .gu-mirror {
    position: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  }
  .gu-hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .gu-unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -ms-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
  }
  .gu-transit {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content no-padding no-bounce class="noscroll">
  <div [dragula]='"bag"' [dragulaModel]='items'>
    <div class="gridItem" *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item.index }}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hmm i am actually thinking to just implement my own drag n drop grid and it will be faster than figuring out the dragula thing...will post solution next week monday

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm running into a similar problem, and keep going back and forth between dragula and rolling my own. I got pretty close with the latter, but dragging inside the grid has performance issues.

Comment: Yes I actually implemented my own thing, I can share my code but I think my use case is very specific - all i needed is something similar to iOS hold and drag for small thumbnails